# Me ajudem no jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Código PHP com HTML:

```
<h2 ><?php the_title() ; ?></h2>

<ul class="galeria" >
<?php the_title() ?>
    <li class="pizzadisponivel"><label value="29,99"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?></label></li>
    <spam> <?php the_content() ?> </spam>
    <button  id="mais"  >+1</button>
    <button  id="menos"  >-1</button>
</ul>

<?php
endwhile; 
endif;
?>
    <label id="teste"=>R$0.00</label>   
    <button  class="col-12" id="btn"  >Finalizar Compra</button>
```

Código jQuery:

```
var Total = parseFloat('0');

var P = $('label').attr('value');

var Pp = (P.replace(/,/,'.'));

$('#mais').click(function(e)){
    Total += parseFloat(Pp)
    $("#teste").html('R$' + parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2));
});

$('#menos').click(function(e)){
    Total -= parseFloat(Pp)
    $("#teste").html('R$' + parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2));
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
alert('Sua compra foi finalizada.');
```

Tenho esse código, gostaria de fazer os botões ("#mais" , "#menos") funcionarem, estou tendo problemas.

Comment: fez debug no navegador? pelo que vi falta ponto e virgula após o parsefloat(Pp), não vi erro de lógica.

Comment: **Recomendo** forte mente que leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/14213), a sua se enquadra em no minimo 3 tópicos de la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código possuía alguns errinhos ali na função click

```
$('#mais').click(function(e)){
```

Você fechou dois parêntesis em vez de um só, porque esse já esta fechado la no final. E o que faltava ali, era como voce tem mais de um label, voce precisa identificar qual label você quer pegar o atributo value, no caso você colocou :

```
    var P = $('label').attr('value');
```

Quando, em vez disso voce deveria identificar qual label você quer pegar o value, no caso é o label que esta dentro do `<li>` com a classe pizzadisponivel, entao fiz assim:

```
 var P = $('.pizzadisponivel label').attr('value');
```

E também faltavam alguns ";". O código corrigido ficou assim, Espero ter ajudado:

```
    <script>
        var Total = parseFloat('0');

        var P = $('.pizzadisponivel label').attr('value');

        var Pp = (P.replace(/,/,'.'));



$('#mais').click(function(e){
    Total += parseFloat(Pp);
    $("#teste").html('R$' + parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2));
});


$('#menos').click(function(e){
    Total -= parseFloat(Pp);
    $("#teste").html('R$' + parseFloat(Total).toFixed(2));
});

</script>
```